# Show live tweets for a certain hashtag, but a year ago

Tags: twitter

I need to make a twitter page to show the tweets that happened a year ago for a certain hashtag.

The page should show the tweets wrote, but a year ago right in this time "hour, min, second".

I looked in the twitter API and i didn't get anything useful.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

For search you can use the `since` and `until` operators.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search

but you may have issues retrieving tweets from a year ago, or even 2 weeks ago.

To overcome this I suggest looking into Snapbird API

https://github.com/remy/snapbird